# Android: Migrating Room database after splitting project into modules

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm attempting to migrate my database after I've split the project into modules.

In the new structure, every module has its own database.

So I want to do something like this:

```
appDatabase.db -> moduleA.db; moduleB.db; moduleC.db
```

The tables themselves have not been changed - only moved to different database.

I know it is possible to do something like

```
"INSERT INTO newTable (userid, username, last_update) SELECT userid, username, last_update FROM oldTable");
```

However, is this possible if "oldTable" is in a different database? How can I access it? Is there a better way to do this migration? Is it possible at all?

Thank you in advance! <3